# Filippov regularization : $\dot x(t)\in F(x(t))$ where $F(x)=\bigcap_{m(N)=0}\bigcap_{\delta >0}co(f(B_\delta (x)\setminus N)$. Where $F$ comes from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let consider the system $$\dot x(t)=f(x(t))\tag{E}$$
where $$f(x)=\begin{cases}f_R(x)&x>0\\0&x=0\\ f_L(x)&x<0\end{cases},$$

where $f_R$ and $f_L$ are $\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$. The way to interpret $(E)$ is as the differential inclusion $$\dot x(t)\in F_f(x(t)),$$
where $$F_f(x)=\bigcap_{m(N)=0}\bigcap_{\delta >0}\text{co}(f(B_\delta (x)\setminus N),$$
where the first intersection is over the nulls sets for Lebesgue measure over $\mathbb R$ and $\text{co}(A)$ denotes the convex hull of the set $A$.

---

**Question :** This function $F_f$ looks to come a bit from nowhere. Could someone explain to what it correspond ? And what is the motivation to consider such a function $F_f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both $f_R(0)$ and $f_L(0)$ are positive, you want to exclude the "isolated" value $f(0)=0$ and all connecting values from the sliding-mode right side. You want only the segment between $f_L(0)$ and $f_R(0)$ as the value of $F_f(0)$. In general the right side for the Filippov problems is a Lebesgue class of functions (or even more distributional), where any two representatives are equal in value up to a null set. Because of this uncertainty, one has to allow to ignore the values over a null set in the construction of $F_f$.

---

If the right side of an ODE is a distribution, one may in some cases have an intuitive idea what a solution might look like. Filippov formalizes that, shortly as the limit set of all solutions that are obtained when the right side is approximated (in the distributional sense) by a sequence of continuous functions. This limit set does not need to be a unique function.

However for some restricted classes of right sides, these limit functions can be characterized in a more straightforward manner using this regularization, without invoking the class of all approximation sequences.

In even more special cases the switching points are well isolated, the solution can be subdivided in segments that are clearly in one phase or another or in the sliding mode between two phases. This is the case that you use as example to discuss the usefulness of the more general theory. Of course, if one talks about computable examples, these fall generally in this last most restricted class.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will see your answer later and let you know if I have any question :)

Comment: I agree that my question sounds a bit silly (sorry for that), but why do we do that ? This looks for me very complicated. Isn't it possible to just say that $x(t)=\int_0^t f_R(x(s))ds$ if  $x(s)>0$ for all $s\in(0,t)$, $x(t)=\int_0^t f_L(x(s))ds$ if $x(s)<0$ for all $s\in (0,t)$ and when $x(t)=0$, then $x(t)=\int_0^t F_{slide}(x(s))ds$. Thien $x$ is a piecwise $C^1$ and the derivative is well define a.e. (only when $x$ reach or leave the switching manifold). This is how I see these system, and I don't really see the point by doing this regularization that looks very complicated,

Comment: and to say more or less just I've just said. Sorry, I know my question is not very constructive (it sounds a bit why the derivative is useful ? and I don't like this sort of question, since it really depend on the context). But I'm very curious to understand why someone develop such a tool to at the end just have an ODE where the solution is not $C^1$ but piecwise $C^1$. Thanks in advance for your time and your consideration.